# Can't open vscode, Error: spawn code ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I'm making a Node project that needs to open a file in VS Code. I was accomplishing this with `` execSync(`code ${filename}`) ``, but that's a security risk if filename is unsanitized, so I tried using spawnSync instead(`spawnSync("code", [filename])`), but it can't find code now and says Error: spawn code ENOENT.

Answer (score 0):

Use "code.cmd" instead of "code", like this:

```js
spawnSync("code.cmd", [filename]);
```